# How can I dealloc manually UIViewController from another UIViewController in UINavigationController without import the first UIViewController class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, dealloc

I've a navigationController. The first viewcontroller is a kind of class FirstViewController. When I tap a button in FirstViewController, it push in navigationController the second viewController that is a kind of class SecondViewController. When I tap a button in SecondViewController, I'd like to dealloc the FirstViewController (previously saved in navigationController) so as to start again as if it was the first time that I open the FirstViewController when I tap back button in navigationItem of SecondViewController. Here the code of the method called when I tap the button in secondViewController:

```
NSArray * navigationPath = [self.navigationController viewControllers];
UIViewController *previousVC = [navigationPath objectAtIndex:[navigationPath count]-2];
[previousVC performSelector:@selector(viewDidUnload)];
```

It doesn't dealloc the FirstViewController. There is a way to do it?

Comment: u should not deallocate manually, the dealloc method for an object is called by runtime when object's retain count reduces to zero, and also there is no need to dealloc your first view controller, (it might be) rootviewcontroller u should change the design

Answer (score 3):

Create a new first view controller

> FirstViewController *first = [[FirstViewController alloc]init];

Reset the navigation stack

> [self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[first, self] animated:NO];

Navigate to first

> [self.navigationController popViewController:YES];

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reset the array of view controllers in the navigation controller.

In your second view controller:

```
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[self] animated:NO];
```

Comment: in this way if I tap back button it does nothing